# Swift unstructured task is not executed

Tags: swift, concurrency, unstructured-task

I’m having an issue with unstructured tasks in my code. I have following function that is implemented in [`AsyncOperation`](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/asynchronous-operations/) subclass, operation is finished in `completion` closure implementation. Randomly, code inside an unstructured task does not execute. In logs, I see “starting unstructured task,” but not “in unstructured task”.

```
func fetchUpdatedObjectsFromServer(completion: @escaping ((Bool)->())) {
    self.apiService().fetchUpdatedObjects(withIds: self.objIds) { [weak self] err, responseObj in
        if let _error = err {
            print(_error)
            completion(false)
        }
        else {
            print("starting unstructured task")
            Task {
                print("in unstructured task")
                await storeObjectsInDB()
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    fetchUpdatedObjectsFromServer() { [weak self] _ in
        print("operation finishing")
        self?.finish()
    }
}
```

Operation queue is running max 5 concurrent operations but there are 3-4 operations queues.

Comment: I'm using AsyncOperation (https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/asynchronous-operations/) and subclassing it for my custom operation. `finish()` is called in completion handler, which is called from `Task` block in case of success response

Comment: @Rob I was aware that this was for an Operation. I suppose my first point is expected behavior for an async operation. Reviewing the code again a day later I realize now I misread the code initially so my second point was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely candidate for `Operation`-related problems is if you ever “wait” for the operations to finish (e.g., [`addOperations(_:waitUntilFinished:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1408358-addoperations) with `true` for `waitUntilFinished`, or a call to [`waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1407971-waituntilalloperationsarefinishe)). Both of those block the calling thread.

The `Task {…}` will run on a thread from the “cooperative thread pool”, or, if isolated to the main actor, will run on the main thread. The main actor scenario is probably obvious, but it is problematic even in the non-actor-isolated scenarios.

The Swift concurrency cooperative thread pool is extremely limited, even more limited than GCD’s worker thread pools. As WWDC 2021’s [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/?time=1239) says, “The [cooperative] thread pool will only spawn as many threads as there are CPU cores, thereby making sure not to overcommit the system.” So, if you ever block a thread from the cooperative thread pool, you can find yourself quickly exhausting this pool, and new tasks will be unable to run.

It is for this reason that we have a “contract” with the Swift concurrency system to never block threads. As that [video says](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/?time=730) “the operating system needs a runtime contract that threads will not block”. That means you must never “wait” for operations (or semaphores, or dispatch groups, or locks, or some slow synchronous work, etc.) from within the Swift concurrency system. Only `await` is safe.

If we maintain this Swift concurrency contract, and never wait for operations, then you should never have this problem where the `Task` will fail to run. In the case of an operation queue, rather than waiting, we would generally wrap the “completion” work inside its own operation, and make this operation dependent upon the preceding operations. Or sometimes you can achieve the desired behavior by using a barrier on the operation queue.

---

While `Operation` was an elegant way to manage dependencies between asynchronous units of work before the advent of `async`-`await`, operations are now an anachronism. Today, we would reach for Swift concurrency tasks, task groups, etc. If you cannot yet tackle that for pragmatic reasons, I get it. But for the sake of future readers, I would discourage the use of operation queues in a world of Swift concurrency.